# Мальчиш Кибальчиш

Tags: этимология, литература

Меня всегда интересовало, откуда Аркадий Гайдар взял имя Кибальчиш? Интересно, это просто набор звуков в рифму, или имя что-то означает?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мало кому известна история происхождения странного имени Мальчиш-Кибальчиш. С Мальчишом-Плохишом всё понятно. Тогда почему правильного мальчика не назвать Хорошиш? Как выяснилось, на то было несколько причин. Во-первых, Хорошиш – слишком примитивно, лобово, да и звучит неблагозвучно. А самое главное – в первоначальном варианте Мальчиша звали не Кибальчиш, а Кипальчиш. То есть мальчик в кипе. Именно еврейский мальчик, по задумке Аркадия Гайдара, должен был дать смертельный бой злобным буржуинам. Возможно, такая идея была продиктована тайным увлечением идеями Троцкого – ведь первый свой рассказ Гайдар назвал «Р.В.С.» – в честь Революционного Военного Совета, которым Троцкий руководил в самые сложные годы гражданской войны. Причём Гайдар не побоялся опубликовать рассказ с таким названием в то время, когда Троцкий уже попал в опалу. Возможно, эту идею писателю подсказала жена, Рахиль Лазаревна Соломянская. Как бы там ни было, в последний момент Аркадий Петрович заменил в имени Мальчиша одну букву. Таким и узнала его большая Советская страна

Comment: "Еврейский мальчик" - это нечто... 
Из Абсурдопедии, что ли?

Comment: Полюбуйтесь на источник этого бреда.
http://www.promegalit.ru/publics.php?id=5385

Comment: "Кипальчиш" - дикое сочетание, совершенно не звучит...

Comment: @behemothus, ссылка - чудо! К 1 апреля как раз бы подошла!

Comment: Нет такое предмета, который не мог бы стаать еврейсокй фамилией. (Антон Палыч).    
Нет такой первоапрельской шктки, которую бы не приняли за правду. (я)

Comment: Более всего меня умиляет, что этот ответ приняли!

Comment: Вот это для меня главная несуразица данного форума. Причем, как понимаю, операцию отменить нельзя.

Comment: Автор может отменить, если примет другой ответ. Наверное, модератор тоже.

Comment: Автор не может.

Comment: @Ларf, может. Надо снять галочку с выбранного ответа и поставить перед другим ответом.

Answer (score 4):

Существует версия, что имя  своего героя Аркадий  Гайдар  придумал, взяв  за основу  фамилию  русского  революционера, народовольца, Кибальчича Николая  Ивановича, казненного за участие  в покушении на царя  Александра II.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что Кибальчиш - это намёк на фамилию революционера Кибальчича. (Но свою версию я не проверяла.)

Николай Иванович Кибальчич (31 [19] октября 1853, Черниговская губерния — 15 [3] апреля 1881, Санкт-Петербург) — русский революционер, народоволец, изобретатель, участник покушения на Александра II (из Википедии).

Comment: У меня тоже сразу была аллюзия к фамилии Кибальчич. Интересно, правы мы или нет?)))

Comment: Да, намек достаточно прозрачен.

Answer (score 1):

Вильям Баткин (
http://jerusalem-korczak-home.com/np/ped/np162.html  ) утверждает, что дальний родственник Н.Кибальчича - Виктор Серж:

" Сказочный и гордый Мальчиш-Кибальчиш ближе к реальной истории, чем может показаться. Был такой французский коминтерновец, переводчик «Двенадцати» Блока, писатель Виктор Серж (под этим литературным псевдонимом скрывался друг Гайдара по фамилии Кибальчич, по-французски звучит Кибальчиш). Известно, что он, прогремевший на весь мир яростной защитой Троцкого, естественно, упрятанный в советские казематы, был буквально выдернут оттуда усилиями французских «буржуинов» как раз в пору создания «Военной тайны»".

Comment: Можете привести источник?

Comment: Источник не внушает доверия, как и версия, behemothus его уже указал. Я по наивности тогда тоже поверила, (тогда была после инфаркта и только осваивала Интернет, не представляла себе, что могут быть такие "юморные" сайты) а потом уже и забыла про этот вопрос, а Вы раскопали. Теперь про Гайдара знаю много,  ответ заменила, эта версия вполне внушает доверие.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо бы было высказать это сомнение своей бабушке. Замена в фамилии одной буквы не дает созвучия: "Мальчиш-Киб'альчич", что ли? Скорее было наоборот. Сначала интуитивно подбиралось гордое прозвище, которое, как оказалось, на одну букву различается с фамилией участника теракта.

Answer (score 0):

В толковом словаре Вл. Даля "кибалка" - шапочка под повязку; чувашская женская верхняя рубаха, которую и русские бабы носят в работе".

Возможно, так был одет мальчиш-кибальчиш.

Answer (score 0):

Киба — река в Шимском и Батецком районе Новгородской области. Мальчик родом с реки Кибы.

Answer (score 0):

На объективность не претендую, просто одна из версий. Гайдар достаточно долго воевал в Хакасии. Хакасский язык входит в группу тюркских и очень близок с киргизским и чувашским. У слова "кибал" в тюркских языках несколько значений: 1) особая национальная островерхая шапка; 2) портной; 3) верёвки или возжи. Исходя из этих трёх переводов можно предположить, что: а) Кибальчиш — это мальчик в остроконечной шапке, будёновке, т. е. красноармеец; б) просто мальчик из семьи портных, т. е. пролетарий-бедняк; ну и в) мальчик-вожак — тот, который правит вожжами. Ещё раз повторяюсь, это просто версии.

Answer (score -2):

– Мальчи́ш-Кибальчи́ш — положительный персонаж сказки Аркадия Гайдара «Сказка о Военной тайне, о Мальчише-Кибальчише и его твёрдом слове

### в первоначальном варианте Мальчиша звали не Кибальчиш, а Кипальчиш. То есть мальчик в кипе. Именно еврейский мальчик, по задумке Аркадия Гайдара, должен был дать смертельный бой злобным буржуинам. Возможно, такая идея была продиктована тайным увлечением идеями Троцкого – ведь первый свой рассказ Гайдар назвал «Р.В.С.» – в честь Революционного Военного Совета, которым Троцкий руководил в самые сложные годы гражданской войны. Причём Гайдар не побоялся опубли-ковать рассказ с таким названием в то время, когда Троцкий уже попал в опалу. Возможно, эту идею писателю подсказала жена, Рахиль Лазаревна Соломянская. Как бы там ни было, в последний момент Аркадий Петрович заменил в имени Мальчиша одну букву. Таким и узнала его большая Советская страна
[Мальчиш Кибальчиш](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88)

\ כי בעל צאי איש /  Ки баъль ци иш // Ки баль чи иш- "потому что хозяин вышел ко мне - се муж" ("хозяин" - это тов. Сталин).

Раби Хаим Кибальчишер был страшно беден. Однако ни разу он не зашел зимой в чей-нибудь дом, чтобы погреться. Когда его спросили о причине, он ответил, с трудом сдерживая горечь: «Мне так холодно у себя в доме, что я опасаюсь зайти в дом другого человека, чтобы, не дай Б-г не нарушить запрет «не завидуй»… (Сиах сарфэй кодэш 4-601) http://www.breslev.co.il/articles/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.aspx?id=15772&language=russian

### Нетривиальный вариант ответа: на древнешумерском "ки-баль" означает "мятежная страна":

## כיא באל / Ki bal – «Страна  как остров ++  в силе, в Боге» -  это Советская страна, С.С.С.Р.

### На объективность не претендую, просто одна из версий. Гайдар достаточно долго воевал в Хакасии. Хакасский язык входит в группу тюркских и очень близок с киргизским и чувашским.
У слова "кибал" в тюркских языках несколько значений: 1) особая национальная островерхая шапка;   Исходя из этого можно предположить, что: а) Кибальчиш — это мальчик в остроконечной шапке, будёновке, т. е. красноармеец;

Высокая остроконечная шапка (подобная короне фараонов Верхнего Египта) была в Степи признаком высокого положения: Кибал \ כי בעל / ки баъл – « потому что хозяин, муж».   Высокие головные уборы носят киргизские знатные женщины, мужья которых – баи – вожди родов.